# Get enum from string in C++ using preprocessor

Tags: c++, enums, c-preprocessor

There are plenty solutions how to get text representation of an enum as string with use of C++ proprocessor (for example [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5094430/822644)).

However, I would like to do the conversion in opposite direction in order to mimick switch on strings.

So for example - given the following enum:

```
typedef enum { RIGHT, LEFT, FORWARD, BACKWARD} direction;
```

For small enums, one could define array of strings and use enum values to get the appropriate string, but that is bad for maintanance.

I would like to have some macro which would define a function "direction FromString(char * str)", which would return RIGHT if I have a string "RIGHT".

There are many sollutions for other programming languages like [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211875/mapping-enum-from-string) or [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604424/convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-java), so I don't think that would be such a bad practice.

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163069/c-string-to-enum) to mine, but without using preprocessor.

My current sollution (based on [one of  the answers to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5094430/822644))  looks like this:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define X_DEFINE_ENUM_WITH_STRING_CONVERSIONS_TOENUM(r, data, elem)          \
    if (!strcmp(s, BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE( elem ))) return elem;

#define DEFINE_ENUM_WITH_STRING_CONVERSIONS(name, enumerators)               \
    enum name {                                                              \
        BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(enumerators)                                       \
    };                                                                       \
    inline const name FromString(char * s) {                                 \
         BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(                                              \
             X_DEFINE_ENUM_WITH_STRING_CONVERSIONS_TOENUM,                   \
             name,                                                           \
             enumerators                                                     \
         )                                                                   \
      return ERR;                                                            \
  }
```

One can use it by:

```
   DEFINE_ENUM_WITH_STRING_CONVERSIONS(direction, (RIGHT)(LEFT)(...)(ERR))
```

The downside is that one has to include ERR to handle the case when the string does not match any of the enum names. How to avoid this?

I was thinking, that maybe a much more elegant sollution would be to use
[Boost Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/).

Comment: *"There are many sollutions for other programming languages like C# or Java, so I don't think that would be such a bad practice."* - I don't agree. The fact that it's not bad practice in C# or Java does not necessarily translate to C++.

Comment: So how would you solve my problem otherwise (switch over string tokens)?

Comment: I don't mean to sound unhelpful, but I just don't consider this a problem in the first place. In my opinion, it's at best a very minor annoyance while you type the code, whereas the macro solutions thrown at it will cause real problems, including readability. If I were a maintenance programmer and would have to deal with a bug in your code, one of my first actions would be to eliminate the macro and convert all `switch` statements to `if`- `else if` chains to make it clearer what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this library (disclaimer – I am the author): https://github.com/aantron/better-enums

The relevant method is [_from_string](http://aantron.github.io/better-enums/ApiReference.html#_from_string) (link is to docs). That method raises an exception in case of error. There is another method that [returns an option](http://aantron.github.io/better-enums/ApiReference.html#_from_string_nothrow), similar to `boost::optional`.

If you want to implement your own version, there is a description of the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31362042/2482998) on Stack Overflow. The code in that answer includes an implementation of `_from_string`.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use an array to store strings (C++11 requested)

```
enum colors : int
{
    RED,
    GREEN,
    BLUE,
    MAX // MAX must be always at the end
};

static const char* const colorsString[] =
{
    "RED",
    "GREEN",
    "BLUE",
};

// Ensure your two "lists" size are matching
static_assert(MAX == sizeof(colorsString) / sizeof(colorsString[0]), "Colors must have the same number of elements.");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define your enum using [X-macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635851/real-world-use-of-x-macros) you can easily have a function generated which implements the switch:

```
#include <string>

#define MOUSE_BUTTONS \
X(LeftButton, 1)   \
X(MiddleButton, 2) \
X(RightButton, 4)

enum MouseButton {
    None = 0
#define X(name, value) ,name = value
MOUSE_BUTTONS
#undef X
};

static MouseButton stringAsMouseButton( const std::string &s )
{
#define X(name, value) if ( s == #name ) return name;
MOUSE_BUTTONS
#undef X
    return None;
}
```

Comment: Isn't the code here converting *to* string, not *from* string?

Comment: Good catch @antron -- I copied the code from one of my [previous answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28625475/91757); I fixed the code now so that it does indeed convert a string to an enum value.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one map as below :

```
#define RIGHT_DIR "RIGHT"
#define LEFT_DIR "LEFT"

_directionActionMap[RIGHT_DIR] = RIGHT;
_directionActionMap[LEFT_DIR] = LEFT;
...
```

Then when you want to retrieve enum from string

```
int GetDirectionENUMFromString(const string& str)
{
  int directionEnum;

  std::map<string,int>::iterator iter;

  iter = _directionActionMap.find(str);

  if (iter != _directionActionMap.end())
  {
      directionEnum = (*iter).second;
  }
  else
  {
     directionEnum = -1;
  }

  return directionEnum; 
}
```

Usage :

```
int directionEnum = GetDirectionENUMFromString("RIGHT");

switch( directionEnum )
{
  case RIGHT:
   break;
  case LEFT:
   break;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps

```
#define stringify(name) # name

direction FromString(char * s) {
    if (!strcmp(s, stringify(RIGHT)) return RIGHT;
    if (!strcmp(s, stringify(LEFT)) return LEFT;
    if (!strcmp(s, stringify(FORWARD)) return FORWARD;
    if (!strcmp(s, stringify(BACKWARD)) return BACKWARD;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: That still needs manual definition of the function. I included my sollution which is smiliar to this, but using preporcessor.